# Making an undefined class as friend, and defining it later

Tags: c++, templates, declaration, local, friend

Making an unknown friend

```
template<typename T>
class List
{
protected:

    class a {
        int x;
        int y;
    private:
        friend class b;  // <------------ Why this is not an error? 
    };

    template <typename U > class b {  //If that is not a error this should be an error
        int z;
        U y;
    };

    public:
        List() {
            a* ptr = (a *)new unsigned char[sizeof(a)];
        }
};

int main() {
    List<int>  mylist;
}
```

Please go through this link, I have my questions as comments in the code.
I am trying to make another class a friend of my class. But that class is not know at the time of making friend. What is the C++ rule that allows for it.
Later I am defining that class in such a way that, it is incompatible with the friend declaration. Why is that not throwing an error. 
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes your code is **invalid**! This is an interesting show of how templates can change meaning of code in subtle ways. The following code *is* valid:

```
class List
{
public:
    class a {
        typedef int type;
        friend class b; // that's fine!
    };

    template <typename U > class b;
};

class b {
  List::a::type an_int; // allowed to access private member
};
```

Standard says at 7.3.1.2/3

> If a friend declaration in a non-local class first declares a class or function83) the friend class or function is a member of the innermost enclosing namespace.

When is it a "first declared class"? It says that too there

> When looking for a prior declaration of a class or a function declared as a friend, and when the name of the friend class or function is neither a qualified name nor a template-id, scopes outside the innermost enclosing namespace scope are not considered.

The lookup for "class b" is delegated from 7.1.5.3/2 to 3.4.4 which in turn delegates to unqualified name lookup at 3.4/7. All the question now is whether the template-name "b" is visible in the friend declaration class a. If it isn't, the name is not found and the friend declaration will refer to a new declared class at global scope. 3.3.6/1 about the scope of it says

> The potential scope of a name declared in a class consists not only of the declarative region following
>   the name’s declarator, but also of all function bodies, default arguments, and constructor ctor-
>   initializers in that class (including such things in nested classes).

Ignoring a few pedantic points that would make this wording not apply to here (which were a defect but are fixed in the C++0x version of that paragraph which also makes this easier to read), this list does not include the friend declaration as an area where that template name is visible.

**However**, the friend was declared in a member class of a class template. When the member class is instantiated *different* lookup applies - the lookup for friend names declared in a class template! The Standard says

> Friend classes or functions can be declared within a class template. When a template is instantiated, the
>   names of its friends are treated as if the specialization had been explicitly declared at its point of instantiation.

So the following code is invalid:

```
template<typename T>
class List
{
public:
    class a {
        typedef int type;
        friend class b; // that's fine!
    };

    template <typename U > class b;
};

// POI
List<int>::a x;
```

When that causes `List<int>::a` to be implicitly instantiated, the name `a` is looked up at "// POI" as if there would have been an explicit specialization declared. In that case, the template `List::b` has already been declared, and this lookup will hit it and emit an error because it's a template and not a non-template class.

Comment: Your analysis seems to be correct except `The name of the friend is not found by simple name lookup until a matching declaration is provided in that namespace scope (either before or after the class declaration granting friendship)`. Your code doesn't get compiled in Comeau, Intel C++ and MSVC++.

Comment: @Prasoon The text you quote has no meaning in this case. The friend's name is not looked up here (the template is looked up). Compiler's don't define the Standard, so I don't argue with compilers accepting or rejecting it. That GCC and Clang accept it is a nice thing, but my answer doesn't depend on them, but merely on the Standard text I quote. Both the EDG frontend (which Intel and Comeau use) and MSVC really have more bugs than this, so that doesn't surprise me).

Comment: I found the text a bit difficult to parse. I might have missed something important. Don't mind. Also have a look at [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282662/template-friend-a-deadly-combination) and a bunch of answers.

Comment: In any case, *if* my analysis is incorrect or *if* there can't be given a correct analysis because the Standard is broken I wish to be shown a Standard's text and argument that shows so :)

Comment: @Johannes : +1, I like Comeau xD `:)`

Answer (score 3):

//Run this- it now will compile for you

```
template <typename U > class b; //<----- forward declaration

template<typename T>
class List
{
protected:


        class a {
        int x;
        int y;
        private:
          friend class b<T>;  // <------------ Add <T>
        };
        template <typename U > class b { 
          int z;
          U y;
        };

        public:
        List() {
          a* ptr = (a *)new unsigned char[sizeof(a)];
        }
};

int main() {
    List<int>  mylist;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The code is ill-formed and Comeau rejects it giving the following error

```
error: invalid redeclaration of type name "b" (declared at
      line 11)
```

I think this is a bug in g++. Intel C++ rejects it too. You can fix the code by defining class `B` above `A`.

```
template <typename U > class b { 
        int z;
        U y;
};
class a {
        int x;
        int y;
    private:
        friend class b<T>;  
};
```

Comment: Thank you. But the interesting thing in your post is that on other compilers it is a redeclaration error. As far as I know redeclaration is not an error, shouldn't it have said conflicting declaration of different type?

Comment: @user420536 : Not necessarily. On MSVC++ I get `List<T>::b' : non-class template has already been declared as a class template.` (redeclaration error). Different compilers are allowed to parse the code differently thereby are allowed to emit different error messages. I don't find anything wrong with that error message. `:)`